# Toggle like button for multiple elements with js

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a JS beginner and I'm trying to create a personal project, but I have some problems with implementing a toggle like button for multiples pictures.
below u can see my button but is working only to one photo. how can a create a loop for the same button to work on every picture that a have in my project? Please help me!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

    <script src="index.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>   
    <button class="like__btn">
        <span id="icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></span>
        <span id="count">0</span> Like
     </button>   
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const likeBtn = document.querySelector(".like__btn");

let likeIcon = document.querySelector("#icon");   
count = document.querySelector("#count");  
let clicked = false;

likeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {  
  if (!clicked) {    
    clicked = true;    
    likeIcon.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>`;
    count.textContent++;
  } else {
    clicked = false;   
    likeIcon.innerHTML = `<i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>`;  
    count.textContent--;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `class` instead of `id` attribute for `span` tags and then
get all buttons by `querySelectorAll` then create a loop and attach `click` event to those buttons.

Here is working sample:

```js
const likeBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".like__btn");
likeBtn.forEach(function (item) {
    item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        let likeIcon = item.querySelector(".icon");
        let count = item.querySelector(".count");
        if (+count.textContent == 0) {
            clicked = true;
            likeIcon.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>`;
            count.textContent++;
        } else {
            clicked = false;
            likeIcon.innerHTML = `<i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>`;
            count.textContent--;
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" />
<button class="like__btn">
    <span class="icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></span>
    <span class="count">0</span> Like
</button>

<button class="like__btn">
    <span class="icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></span>
    <span class="count">0</span> Like
</button>

<button class="like__btn">
    <span class="icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></span>
    <span class="count">0</span> Like
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working now. this is really very helpful for me. again, thanks